# Getting missing FastCGIModule error for executing php code inside IIS

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I'm trying to load an HTML file containing php script inside it. It is hosted in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 x64. Here is the HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<H1>test</H1>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I've hosted this page as a web application inside IIS. My web.config is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI_HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I browse the html file in browser it results in following error:

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler
>   "PHP53_via_FastCGI_HTML" has a bad module "FastCgiModule" in its
>   module list

I've double checked following things:

1. CGI component is already installed in windows components/features in control panel.
2. ApplicationHost.config file of IIS containing following add tag inside `<globalModules>` tag:

   add name="FastCgiModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\iisfcgi.dll"
3. ApplicationHost.config file of IIS is containing following add tag inside `<Modules>` tag:

   add name="FastCgiModule"

Some additional information related to FastCgiModule present in ApplicationHost.config. I see the following tags also present in handlers section. I've clipped them for brevity:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
                <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
                <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
```

Still I'm getting above mentioned error. Can anyone help me what I'm missing now?

Comment: You need to have an entry under `ISAPI and CGI Restrictions` at server level for this FastCGI handler.

Comment: @LexLi Can you give me little bit more direction on how to make those changes? Are you asking me to make these changes in `applicationHost.config` or somewhere in IIS? I've added some more details on what I found in handlers section in server level IIS configuration file.

Comment: open IIS Manager and find the icon for "ISAPI and ...", then you can click it and the Help icon to learn more.